# "Joined him at" or "joined him in"?

Tags: prepositions

> I joined Tom **at** Flora's walk-in closet.
>   I joined Tom **in** Flora's walk-in closet.

What's the correct preposition? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In, at, on* are prepositions of place. Generally,

- *on* is used for position on a surface,
- *at* for a specific place or point,
- *in* for enclosed or surrounding space.

*Walk-in closet* is a closet that is large enough to walk around in -  in other words, an enclosed space. Hence, you joined Tom **in** Flora's walk-in closet.

Comment: Only if Tom was actually in the closet, otherwise he joined Tom at the closet.

Comment: What @JoeDark says. It depends on exactly where Tom is. In a weird house I wouldn't rule out even the possibility you joined Tom on Flora's closet assuming it has a roof of some kind that you could sit/stand on. And you could certainly also join him above the closet assuming a multistoried house.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the place or activity  where the joining takes place.

He joined her at the bar.

He joined her at the podium.

She joined her sister on stage.

Tom joined his friends at the restaurant.

Jane joined Mary in the restaurant washroom and asked what was going on with her boyfriend, who had been acting strange.

She joined him at the theater entrance.

She joined him at the stadium's east gate.

He joined his pals at the poker table.

He joined her in song.

He joined her in making fun of grandma's butterfly tattoo.